# I am trying to upload a csv file onto Python (Azure) but am running into file IO Error does not exist

Tags: python, azure

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('Project_Wind_Data.csv'), usecols = ['U100', 'V100']) with open 
('Project_Wind_Data.csv',"r") as csvfile:
```

I am trying to access certain columns within the csv file. I recive an error message saying that the data file does not exist

My data is in the following form:

[image]

This is must a be trivial issue but help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please format your code properly. Why do you need `with open 
('Project_Wind_Data.csv',"r") as csvfile:`

Comment: @Mechanic Could i have a suggestion s to how it should be? As I am new to Python.

Comment: Appears that you've already asked this same question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50759366/i-am-trying-to-upload-a-csv-data-file-to-python-and-access-certain-columns-but-i) - please don't post the same question multiple times. Just update the original question with more details. One of these two questions needs to be closed (since they appear to be the same question, just phrased differently).

Answer (score 0):

If your csv file is in the same working directory as your .py code, you use directly

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('Project_Wind_Data.csv'), usecols = ['U100', 'V100'])
```

If the file is in another directory, replace `'Project_Wind_Data.csv'` with the full path to the file like `c:User/Documents/file.txt`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am unsure if my files are within the same directory as I am using  Microsoft Azure, is there anyway I can find a link for the path from azure?

Comment: You can find the details to download/access the file from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-python-how-to-use-file-storage